# Wunderlist Facebook signin on iPhone?

Tags: facebook

I signed up to Wunderlist on the Chrome app using my Facebook login, but now I am trying to log in on my iPhone and there is no Facebook option and none of my normal passwords works if I sign in under my email. What am I to do?

Comment: I figured it out. I installed the Mac version and chose "forgot passowrd" and sent myself a new password.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose the "forgot password" option to get a new password. Then once you log in with the new password that will be sent to you, you can change it once you're inside. :)

Comment: I did try that, but it makes you put in your existing password, which wasn't working.